# django query using and clause

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

How to use `and` clause in Django

For ex:

```
    select Date(timestamp) from userlog where (Date(timestamp) >= "2008-01-02" and Date(timestamp) <= "2009-01-02") and ipaddress != "192.168.2.211";


  Django query:

     userlog.objects.filter(timestamp__range=(startdate,enddate),ipaddress !="192.168.2.211")
```

In the above there is an error saying `non-keyword arg afterkeyword arg` and the error is in the above line

ipaddress is a char field,Am i constructing the query wrong if so how this should be resolved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
userlog.objects.filter(timestamp__range=(startdate,enddate),ipaddress !="192.168.2.211")
```

The use of `!=` is not correct in Django (or indeed, not in Python). In order to exclude all records with `ipaddress` matching a certain value you should use the `exclude()` mechanism.

```
userlog.objects.filter(timestamp__range=(startdate,enddate)).exclude(ipaddress = 
        "192.168.2.211")
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the `and` clause. The issue is that `ipaddress !="192.168.2.211"` is an invalid filter expression in Django. You can *only* use the equals sign in filter expressions, because they are actually keyword arguments to the filter method.

In your case, you can need to do:

```
userlog.objects.filter(timestamp__range=(startdate,enddate)
                      ).exclude(ipaddress="192.168.2.211")
```